# Saving decoded images from an autoencoder

Tags: python, opencv, keras, autoencoder

So, this part of an autoencoder Keras code, which can be seen, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349535/valueerror-error-when-checking-input-expected-input-1-to-have-shape-none-655), tries to reconstruct the encoded image:

```
decoded_images = decoder.predict(encoded_images)
```

I'm trying after that to save the decoded images, as follows:

```
for i in range(len(decoded_images)):
    cv2.imwrite(results_directory + '/' + str(i),decoded_images[i])
```

I however get the following error:

```
cv2.error: /dev/shm/ebuser/OpenCV/2.4.13.3/gmkl-2016.4/opencv-2.4.13.3/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:275: error: (-2) could not find a writer for the specified extension in function imwrite
```

Why is that? How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that I simply need to add an extension, for instanse `.jpg`, as follows:

> cv2.imwrite(results_directory + '/' + str(i) +
>   '.jpg',decoded_images[i])